# C++: Default initialize an integral type in a template function

Tags: c++, templates

For educational purposes I am wrting my own C++ numerical vector template class. I want to be able to write (v, w) for the dot product of two vectors and consequently overload `operator,()` as follows:

```
template<class T>
const T Vector<T>::operator,(const Vector<T>& v) const
{
    assertEqualSize(v);

    T t;
    for(size_t i=0; i<numElements; i++) {
        t += elements[i] * v[i];
    }
    return t;
}
```

My question now is: how do I properly initialize `t` with a sensible value (e.g. `0.0` for `Vector<double>`)? I tried `T t();` but then g++ tells me, e.g., that "double(*)()" cannot be converted to "const double" at the return statement and that `operator+=()` would not be defined for "(double(), double)".

Thank you very much!

Comment: using `(v,w)` for the dot product is rather odd. Why not simply overload the `*`, i.e. `v*w` for the dot product? (that's what I use). In 3D, the vector product can be implemented using `^`. Of course, multiplication by scalar or matrix can also be implemented using (another overload of) `*`.

Comment: I agree that re-using the comma operator si not a good idea. It will lead to confusing code. Unfortunately re-using `*` isn't a great idea either, because it isn't unambiguous, cross product being an obvious candidate. I usually provide functions for binary operations involving vectors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is termed *value initialization*, which has the effect of zero-initializing built-in types:

```
T t{};     // C++11
T t = T(); // C++03 and C++11
```

The reason this doesn't work

```
T t();
```

is that it is a declaration of a parameterless function called `t`, returning a `T`.

Comment: That's a templated version of MVP isn't it?

Comment: @Borgleader, MVP is more `Foo foo(Bar());`, but yeah.

Comment: @Borgleader it is definitely a VP, but MVP is even more V :)

Comment: Thank you very much juanchopanza! Now that you laid it out like this I feel pretty dumb ;)

Comment: @o.svensson nothing to feel dumb about: these are two "special" features of the language at play: parsing everything that can look like a function as one, and not initializing default constructed built-in types.

Comment: @juanchopanza What's wrong with `T t(0)` (for built-in types)?

Comment: @Walter Nothing in the code forces T to be a built-in type. So this could potentially introduce errors.

Comment: @o.svensson I know, but what happens with `T t{}` for in this case? Doesn't it simply call the default constructor (without any guarantee of proper initialisation)? This would imply that the answer given is wrong (as it only works for built-in types, while the OP didn't specify that).

Comment: @Walter no, it is a value initialization, as I said in the answer. This basically translates to "call the default constructor for user defined types and zero-initialize built-ins".

Comment: Still, that assumes that `T()` is zero in the relevant sense. I.e. `a+=T()` is a no-op for all `a`, including `a==T()`.

Comment: @MSalters quite right. I think the answer is just wrong (or perhaps "incomplete"): it only works for certain types.

Comment: @Walter It only works for certain types, like all standard library algorithms and containers. I do not see a problem in that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does allow for **any type `T`**, including user-defined ones, when simple *value initialisation* calls the **default constructor** and hence may **fail to zero-initialise**. I would be surprised if you intended other than built-in types `T`, but users of your code may have other ideas ... You should safeguard against that, e.g. via SFINAE:

```
template<class T>
struct is_complex { static const bool value = false; };
template<class U>
struct is_complex<std::complex<U>> : std::is_floating_point<U> {};

template<class T>
typename
std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value || is_complex<T>::value,
               T>::type
T Vector<T>::operator,(const Vector<T>& v) const
{
   T t{};  // value-initialisation is now guaranteed to be zero-initialisation
   /* ... */
}
```

Of course, this type of SFINAE may be applied to the `class Vector<T>` as a whole (instead of applying it to selected methods).

---

Just to clarify: this substantially restricts the possible types `T` to only 6 allowed types (`float`, `double`, `long double`, and the corresponding `std::complex<>` types). Of course, one can allow integer types, but I would be surprised if you want vector operations for integer vectors.

Comment: There is no way to safe-guard against user defined types whose default constructor does not perform zero-initialization of its elements. How does your code guarantee such zero initialization?

Comment: @juanchopanza For such types SFINAE disables the function. Only floating-point types or `std::complex<floating-point type>` are allowed.

Comment: The point is how do you identify such types? You would need to know the internals of their default constructor, and determine that they are not zero initializing something that should be. I cannot see how SFINAE would do that.

Comment: @juanchopanza You didn't get it. I'm *not using SFINAE to disable types without zero initialisation*. Rather I'm using SFINAE to **enable floating-point types** (and `std::complex<>`). Just read the code man.

Comment: But there is no need for that, man. Why would you want to enable only floating point types and std::complex??

Comment: @juanchopanza so that `T t{}` is guaranteed to zero-initialise. How else can you guaranteed zero initialisation? You could, of course, also allow built-in integer types and certain explicit user-defined types for which you *know* (at the time of writing the `operator,`) that they have zero-initialising default construction, but not any type `T`, since they may not zero-initialise.

Comment: You guarantee *default construction* for user defined types. It is up to the user/author of those types to make sure default construction does something sensible. There is no way of ensuring that.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, I think this is a difference in philosophy: you want to trust the user, I don't. Yours is more flexible but potentially unsafe, mine is safe but restrictive.